# Finding longest match between 2 files from pattern

Tags: perl, pattern-matching, substring, hashtable

I am having trouble implementing two files within this program. I am trying to to access the contents of file `$Q` and `$s`.

```
print "Input the K value \n";
$k = <>;
chomp $k;

print "Input T\n";
$t = <>;
chomp $t;

%Qkmer = ();                      
$i = 1;

$query=' ';
while ($line=<IN>) {
chomp($line);
 if ($line=~ m/^>/ ) {
 next;
}
$query=$query.$line;
$line=~ s/(^|\n)[\n\s]*/$1/g;

 while (length($line) >= $k) {
   $line =~ m/(.{$k})/;
   if (! defined $Qkmer{$1}) {#every key not deined as the first match
     $Qkmer{$1} = $i;
   }
   $i++;
   $line = substr($line, 1, length($line) -1);
 }
}

open(MYDATA, '<', "data.txt");

while ($line=<MYDATA>) { \
  chomp($line);
  %Skmer = ();           # This initializes the hash called Skmer.
  $j = 1;

  if ($line=~ m/^>/ ) { #if the line starts with >
    next; #start on next line #separated characters
  }
  $line=~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g ; #remove all spaces from file
  while (length($line) >= $k) {
    $line =~ m/(.{$k})/;#match any k characters and only k characters in dna
    $Skmer{$1} = $j; #set the key position to $j and increase for each new key
    $j++;
    $line = substr($line, 1, length($line) -1); #this removes the first character in the current string
  }

  ###(56)###for($Skmerkey(keys %Skmer)){
    $i=$Skmer{$Skmerkey};
    if(defined $Qkmer($Skmerkey)){
      $j=$Qkmer($Skmerkey);
      }
      $S1=$line;
      $S2=$query;
      @arrayS1= split(//, $S1);
      @array2= split(//, $S2);

      $l=0;
      while($arrayS1[$i-$l] eq $arrayS2[$j-$l]){
        $l++;
      }
      $start=$i-$l;
      $m=0;
      while ($arrayS1[$i+$k+$m] eq $arrayS2[$j+$k+$m]) {
        $m++;
      }
      $length=$l+$k+$m;
      $match= substr($S1, $start, $length);

      if($length>$t){
        $longest=length($match);
        print "Longest: $match of length $longest \n";
      }
  }

}###(83)###
```

The input files contain only strings of letters. For example:

**File 1:**

```
ahhtsagnchjgstffhjyfcsghnvzfhg
```

**File2:**

```
ggujvfbgfgkjfcijjjffcvvafcsghnvzfhgvugxckugcbhfcgh
ghnvzfhgvugxckHhfgjgcfujvftjbvdtkhvddgjcdgjxdjkfrh
ajdbvciyqdanvkjghnvzfhgvugxc
```

From a match of a word of length`$k` in file 1 in file 2, I check from that match in file 2 to left and to right of word for further matches. The final output is the longest match between File 1 and File 2 based on `$k`. Now I ge

With this code, I get a syntax error and I am not suer why because it looks correct to me:

```
syntax error at testk.pl line 56, near "$Skmerkey("
syntax error at testk.pl line 83, near "}"
```

Thank you.

Comment: `$k` used, but not defined. `use warinings; use strict;`

Comment: Hash `%kmer` allways empty !!!

Comment: Yes I just put the code straight in here from my editor so I had to manually add spaces to get everything into one code block. In my actual program, the commented out areas are not commented out. I used the hashes to distinguish areas that I am specifically having trouble with and likely need to implement another way..

Comment: At analysis step in 1 symbol, search in both directions does not make sense.This can be used if increase step in the second file to $k. But in this case, this guarantee find all matches of a minimum length $k*2-1.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;         # <--- Allways use this
use warnings;       # <--- and this
use Data::Dumper;

my $k=3;

open(my $IN, '<', "File2");  # use $IN instead of depricated IN
my $line=0;  # line number
my %kmer;    # hash of arrays of all $k-letter "words" line/position
my @Q;       # rows of Q-file
while(<$IN>) {
  chomp;
  next if /^>/;   
  s/^\s+|\s+$//g; 
  next if !$_;
  my $pos=0;
  push @Q, $_;    # store source row
  for(/(?=(.{$k}))/g) {  # Capture $k letters. floating window with step 1 symbol
   push @{$kmer{$_}}, [$line,$pos];  # store row number and position of "word"
   $pos++;
  }
  $line++;
}

open($IN, '<', "File1");
$line=0;
while(<$IN>) {   # Read S-file
  chomp;
  next if /^>/;
  s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
  next if !$_;
  my $pos=0;
  my $len=length($_);  # length of row of S-file
  my $s=$_;            # Current row of S-file
  my @ignore=();       # array for store information about match tails
  for(/(?=(.{$k}))/g) {
    next if ! $kmer{$_};  # "word" not found try to next
    for(@{$kmer{$_}}) {   # $kmer{word} contains array of lines/positions in Q
      my($qline, $qpos)=@{$_};
#      print "test $qline:$qpos ";
      if( grep {$_->[0]==$qline && $_->[1]==$qpos } @ignore ) {
      # this line/position already tested and included in found matching
#        print "Ignore match tail $qline:$qpos\n";
        next;
      }
      my $j=$k;  # $k letters same, test after this point
      my $qlen=length($Q[$qline]);
      $j++ while( $pos+$j<$len && $qpos+$j<$qlen &&
                  substr($s,$pos+$j,1) eq substr($Q[$qline],$qpos+$j,1) );
      print "MATCH FOUND: S-file line $line pos $pos, Q-file line $qline pos $qpos: ",
            substr($s,$pos,$j),"\n";
      push @ignore, [$qline, $qpos, $j];  # store positions and length of match
    }
  } continue {  # Continue block works on all loops, include after "next"
   $pos++;
   @ignore=grep { # recalculate/filter position and length of all match tails
                  ++$_->[1];  # increment position
                  (--$_->[2]) # decrement length
                   >= $k      # and filter out lengths < $k
                } @ignore;
#   print Dumper(\@ignore);
  }
  $line++;
}
```